# load another php page dynamically in jquery ui on click of a button

Tags: php, jquery

```
jQuery(function ($) { 
    // Load dialog on page load
    // Load dialog on click
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click({
        modal:true,
        open: function ()
        {
            var id = $('#id').attr('value');  
            $(this).load('edit.php?id='+id);
        },
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        title: 'Dynamically Loaded Page'
    });
});
```

This is not opening the dialog on the click of the button. what is it that i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Just looking at `$('#id').attr('value')` - you aren't using the same `id="id"` attribute for more than one element in the page are you? If so, that will cause you problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing options from jQuery UI `.dialog()` to `.click()`. Try this:

```
jQuery(function ($) { 
    // Load dialog on page load
    // Load dialog on click
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function(){
        $('<div id="dialogContainer"></div>').appendTo('body').dialog({
            modal:true,
            open: function ()
            {
                var id = $('#id').attr('value');  
                $(this).load('edit.php?id='+id);
            },
            height: 400,
            width: 400,
            title: 'Dynamically Loaded Page'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: it is still not loading the dialog box on click of the edit button.
the thing is that after retrieving the value from the accounts.php it is forwarded to edit.php & edit.php needs to open in the jquery dialog where i edit all the details for that particular id.

Comment: You could try: `$('#dialogContainer').load('edit.php?id='+id);`. I'm not sure of what `this` is inside the dialog's `open` callback.

Answer (score 0):

try doing things in reverse

```
function getEdit(id)
{
    $.get("edit.php", {id: id}
       function(data)
       {
            $("#div-id").html($("#div-id").html() + data)
            $("#div-id").dialog({
                modal:true,
                height: 400,
                width: 400,
                title: 'Dynamically Loaded Page'
                });
       },
       "html");
}

getEdit(); // you can also set up a button to call this as well.
```